# OpenCV: How to use cvSobel?

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to find the gradient direction from the edges using OpenCv 2.4.5, but I'm having problem with cvSobel() and below is the error message and my code. I read somewhere that it might be due to the conversion between floating point(??) but I have no idea on how to fix it. Any Help??

[image]

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\calib3d\calib3d.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat im = imread("test1.jpg");
    if (im.empty()) {
        cout << "Cannot load image!" << endl;
    }
    Mat *dx, *dy;
    dx = new Mat( Mat::zeros(im.rows, im.cols, 1)); 
    dy = new Mat( Mat::zeros(im.rows, im.cols, 1));

    imshow("Image", im);

    // Convert Image to gray scale
    Mat im_gray;
    cvtColor(im, im_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    imshow("Gray", im_gray);

            //trying to find the direction, but gives errors here
    cvSobel(&im_gray, dx, 1,0,3);


    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't do `dx = new Mat(...`. Not only is it ugly, but you leak the memory as well. Declaring `Mat dx;` is sufficient.

Comment: Ok. I did that because I thought cvSobel() only works with pointer. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the C++ and C api. cv::Mat is from the C++ api and `CvArr*` is from the C api.
here you are using The C api `cvSobel` on C++ classes.

```
//trying to find the direction, but gives errors here
cvSobel(&im_gray, dx, 1,0,3);
```

What happens if you do

```
cv::Sobel( im_gray, dx, im_gray.depth(), 1, 0, 3);
```

**EDIT**
and declare

```
Mat dx;
Mat dy;
```

I think this might solve your problem, I'm actually quite surprised your code compiles.

Comment: I tried that before and it gives me a compiling error as below. A little googling tells me that it should pass the pointer of the Mat..  (>__<)

1>c:\users\_\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cv_scd\cv_scd\test.cpp(47): error C2664: 'cvSobel' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cv::Mat' to 'const CvArr *'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't reading very carefully. I tried again with your method cv::Sobel(im_gray, dx, 1, 0, 3); but it still give me the same error.. T_T

Comment: Yes, I declared Mat dx with your example, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: accoording to your warning you are still calling `cvSobel` not `cv::Sobel`

Comment: @Joqi Sorry had to reinstall OpenCV on my pc to get it to use, it been a while. But to cv::Sobel() also wants to know the destination depth, there things went wrong. see my answer, like that stuff should work, at least at my pc.

Comment: OMG!!! It works now!! You're so awesome!! (>___<)!!! Thanks so much, hetepeperfan!!!